# Subscript without text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want e.g. `\bigtriangleup` as a subscript in math mode, but I do not want it as the subscript of any preceding symbol as `|` as in `|_{\bigtriangleup}`. I tried with `_{\bigtriangleup}` which does not work. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: ${}_{\bigtriangleup}$

Comment: it sounds like you really just want a smaller triangle, placed lower down.  try `{}_{\bigtriangleup}` which will "subscript" it to "nothing" (an empty group).  you may have to adjust spacing manually.

Comment: Just `$_{\bigtriangleup}$` work perfect for me with TeX Live 2013 in a article class. Since it is only a character, also only `$_\bigtriangleup$` work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try with `~_{\bigtriangleup}` or with `\phantom{text}_{\bigtriangleup}`. In the second case the width of `text` determines how much blank space will be left before the subscript.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)